# PHP Detect Pages Genre/Category

Tags: php

I was wondering if their was any sort of way to detect a pages genre/category.

Possibly their is a way to find keywords or something?

Unfortunately I don't have any idea so far, so I don't have any code to show you.

But if anybody has any ideas at all, let me know.

Thanks!

**EDIT @Nican**

Perhaps their is a way to set, let's say 10 category's (Entertainment, Funny, Tech).

Then creating keywords for these category's (Funny = Laughter, Funny, Joke etc).

Then searching through a webpage (maybe using a cUrl) for these keywords and assigning it to the right category.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. What would be a page genre? Could you give an example?

Comment: Are you talking about web crawling or something like that?

Comment: Are you trying to classify a page according to it's content?

Comment: @Charles Yes, Basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folksonomy may be a way of accomplishing what you're looking for:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folksonomy

For instance, in Drupal they have a Folksonomy module:

http://drupal.org/node/19697 (Note this module appears to be dead, see http://drupal.org/taxonomy/term/71)

Couple that with a tag cloud generator, and you may get somewhere:

http://drupal.org/project/searchcloud

Plus, a little more complexity may be able to derive mapped relationships to other terms, especially if you control the structure of the tagging options.

http://intranetblog.blogware.com/blog/_archives/2008/5/22/3707044.html

**EDIT**

In general, the type of system you're trying to build relies on unique word values on a page. So you would need to...

1. Get unique word values from your content (index values or create a bot to crawl your site)
2. Remove all words and symbols you can't use (at, the, or, and, etc...)
3. Count the number of times the unique words appear on the page
4. Add them to some type of datastore so you can call them based on the relationships you're mapping
5. If you have a root label system in place, associate those values with the word counts on the page (such as a query or derived table)

This is very general, and there are a number of ways this can be implemented/interpreted. Folksonomies are meant to "crowdsource" much of the effort for you, in a "natural way", as long as you have a user base that will contribute.

Comment: Could you perhaps supply any further example?

Comment: "Any further examples" is a pretty broad request. If you're looking for code, that would be challenging, since it's a suitably complex topic. I would select a framework and try to work within the context of that framework's developed modules/plugins.

Comment: @Alexwhin, I edited with a vary basic stepwise process. Code_burglar also has a slightly different approach. If you can find a good prewritten class or module, try using it unless you need to build your own.

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is basically what Google Adsense and similar services do, and it's based on analyzing the content of a page and matching it to topics. Generally, this kind of stuff is beyond what you would call simple programming / development and would require significant resources to be invested to get it to work "right".

A basic system might work along the following lines:

- Get page content
- Get X most commonly used words (omitting stuff like "and" "or" etc.)
- Get words used in headings
- Assign weights to different words according to a set of factors (is used in heading, is used in more than one paragraph, is used in link anchors)
- Match the filtered words against a database of words related to a specific "category"
- If cumulative score > treshold, classify site as belonging to category
- Rinse and repeat

Comment: I gathered as much, but honestly it doesn't have to be 100% perfect. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Updated my answer to outline what a basic system might look like